# Cocos2d-x JS 3.7.1 touch event MAC issue

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js, cocos2d-html5

We now working on our first cocos2d-x JS project, got trouble running MAC project. For WEB it's working correctly.

We have created following eventListener:

```
var MouseFetcher;
MouseFetcher = cc.EventListener.create({
    event: cc.EventListener.MOUSE,
    TP: cc.Point,
    initial:function(){
        this.TP = new cc.p(cc.winSize.width/2, cc.winSize.height/2);
    },
    onMouseDown: function (event) {
        this.TP = event.getLocation();
        return true;
    },
    onMouseMove: function (event) {

    },
    onMouseUp:function(event){
        this.TP = event.getLocation();
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < clickables.length; i++){
            if(clickables[i].containsPoint(this.TP)){
                clickables[i].touchEvent();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And there is code part where it is used in eventManager:

```
this.touchListener = MouseFetcher;
this.touchListener.initial();
cc.eventManager.addListener(this.touchListener, this);
```

When we running app we getting following error:

```
frameworks/cocos2d-x/cocos/scripting/js-bindings/auto/jsb_cocos2dx_auto.cpp: Line: 18190, Function: js_cocos2dx_EventDispatcher_addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority
Invalid Native Object
JS: /script/jsb_cocos2d.js:1643:Error: Invalid Native Object
```

Can someone help solve that issue, what we doing wrong for MAC/IOS version? How eventListener should be initialized in that case and used.

Answer (score 0):

"Invalid Native Object" error means that you are using a CCNode that has been released(maybe never added to scene graph and not calling retain(), or has been remove from parent).

In web version, nodes are retained/released automatically, you can still use it even nodes are not added to scene graph; however, in native version you must make sure nodes are still valid before operating it.

In your case, you should check whether the "this" node is valid in below code:

```
this.touchListener = MouseFetcher;
this.touchListener.initial();
cc.eventManager.addListener(this.touchListener, this);
```